# Asymptotic estimate for the integral of Riemann zeta function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I have to show that $$\int_0^T    | \zeta (\sigma+it) |  ^2 dt$$is asymptotic to $\zeta(2\sigma)T$ for $\sigma(=\Re(s))>1$ (I think to have solved) and for $\sigma>1/2$?

Comment: Is t complex or real

Comment: We know that:

$$\zeta\left(\text{s}\right):=\sum_{\text{n}=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\text{n}^\text{s}}$$

When $\Re\left(\text{s}\right)>1$ 

So:

$$\int_0^\text{T}\left|\sum_{\text{n}=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\text{n}^\text{s}}\right|^2\space\text{d}\Im\left(\text{s}\right)\space\le\space\sum_{\text{n}=1}^\infty\int_0^\text{T}\frac{1}{\left|\text{n}^\text{s}\right|^2}\space\text{d}\Im\left(\text{s}\right)=\sum_{\text{n}=1}^\infty\int_0^\text{T}\frac{1}{\text{n}^{2\Re\left(\text{s}\right)}}\space\text{d}\Im\left(\text{s}\right)=\text{T}\cdot\zeta\left(2\cdot\Re\left(\text{s}\right)\right)$$

Comment: You need to estimate $\displaystyle\sum_{n,m, n \ne m} \int_0^T \frac{(n/m)^{it}}{(nm)^\sigma} dt = \sum_{n,m, n \ne m} \frac{(n/m)^{iT}-1}{(nm)^\sigma i\log( n/m)} $. The problem is when $|i\log( n/m)|$ is very small

Comment: t is Real. Thank you Jan Earland, but your proof shows that the integral is $O$, not asymtotic.